# How to save a file via API?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have models User and License. I use m2m to bind users and their licenses, and ForeignKey to create a custom file upload path.

```
@deconstructible
class User_directory_path(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        return f'{instance.user_id}/{self.prefix}_{filename}'

class License(models.Model):
    license_0 = models.FileField(
        storage=MinioBackend(
            bucket_name='django-backend-private',
            replace_existing=True),
        upload_to=User_directory_path('license_0'),
        max_length=255,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class User(models.Model):
    licenses = models.ManyToManyField(License, blank=True, related_name='user_licenses',)
```

So, I can upload a file using ORM:

```
licenses = License.objects.create(user=user)
user.licenses.add(licenses)

with open(f'{test_data}/{doc}', 'rb') as f:
  liceses.license_0.save(name=doc, content=f)
```

But how do I upload a file using the API? For example:

```
class CreateUserTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.url = f'{host}/api/users/'
        self.data = {
            'id': user_id,
            'licenses': {
                'license_0': open(f'{test_data}/important_document.pdf', 'rb'),
            }
        }

    def test_create_user(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.url, self.data, format='multipart', HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=token)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```